# Having more mnemonic bookmarks PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I've used all mnemonic bookmarks from A to Z and I don't want to use the number ones because I'm using it for someone else that is different. Is there a way to make AA, AB, ... bookmarks?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK -- Nope. What is the reason for having that many mnemonic bookmarks? How do you use them? Why can't you use "normal" bookmarks for the same purpose? You can give them names and "encode" some unique text/ID there so you may quickly reach it in the Bookmarks popup (speed search works there if the bookmarks list node is expanded). That works with line bookmarks (does not seem to show them when bookmarking a file).

Comment: I mean I could use "normal" bookmarks but I find the mnemonic bookmarks easier to navigate through. What do you mean by "You can give them names and "encode" some unique text/ID there so you may quickly reach it in the Bookmarks popup (speed search works there if the bookmarks list node is expanded).". You mean at the beginning of the line that is bookmarked I add something to make it easy to search for? Speed search doesn't work for me to find mnemonic bookmarks.

Comment: When you make a line bookmark, you can give it a name/description. So you can give either some unique description or prepend it with `#AA` , then `#AB`) to mimic mnemonics. NOTE: not the line with bookmark, but the bookmark description. And when you open the Bookmarks popup, just start typing (speed search) `#aa` and it will select all entries that have that text. You can navigate between them using Up & Down buttons.

Comment: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/bookmarks.html#rename-delete-bookmarks -- to edit the bookmark description. 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks -- the bookmark popup window (not toolwindow but popup; although the search should also work in toolwindow)

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't even know the bookmark had a description. I guess that'll do the trick, I just have to replace my 28 bookmarks by regular bookmarks now .... rip